# Where can I find mactex-20160603.pkg?

Tags: mactex

For some convoluted reason, I'd like to find a "safe" direct download link to mactex-20160603.pkg. I've had a very hard time to find one where the download speed is >20 KB/s. Any hint ? All the CTAN mirrors seems to have update and don't have it anymore.

Thanks a lot

Comment: How about trying [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73okX.png)?

Comment: Yes so that's what I meant by safe actually :) Is that supposed to be "safe" to download from a torent ? Any risk there ?

Comment: Is there a reason for not wishing to download the `20161009` version of MacTeX, which is available at http://tug.org/mactex/? Almost surely, the only differences between the `20160603` and `20161009` are due to bug fixes and package updates that occurred between June and October of 2016.